# When should we use vision transformers for image classification?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

I am working on classification problem for Covid19, Pneumonia and healthy lung.

I have 3000 images for each class.

- Can I apply vision transformers for this image classification instead of normal CNN?
- Or is there any prerequisite for applying this? I am new to transformers.

I have tried all CNN and they have achieved 95% accuracy till now.

Answer (score 2):

At small to medium datasets, ViTs don't give a performance that is comparable. On really big datasets, however, they have outperformed CNNs. More information [here](https://www.v7labs.com/blog/vision-transformer-guide) https://www.v7labs.com/blog/vision-transformer-guide